# Dynamic Programming: Chessboard

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

A rook starts in the upper left corner of a standard 8 by 8 chessboard. Two players take turns moving the rook either horizontally to the right or vertically downward, as many squares as they like.
Stationary moves are not allowed and Player 1 goes first. The winner is the player that places the rook on the lower right corner square. Say who will win and describe the winning strategy.

I have the above statement problem and I'm interested in seeing how others would approach the problem. I know there is way to calculate the different paths that the rook can take. I tried doing the problem by hand and it always seemed like Player 2 always won but I might be thinking of it too simply. Approaching it in a dynamic programming fashion seemed like a good way to go. Anyway, anyone have any insights, algorithms, or such to approaching this problem!

Comment: Explain "Stationary moves are not allowed".

Comment: @RBarryYoung as in you can't pass on your turn (you can't say your move is to stay on the current spot your in because it would result in a stalemate). you must always make a move to the right or down

Comment: Have you tried playing this game? You might be able to reason a winning strategy, rather than resort to using a computer.

Comment: Games like this can be analysed with *combinatorial game theory* (no relation to Nash's economic game theory). In particular, your game is an *impartial game* - the possible moves are the same for both players.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

**H8** is a winner box so everything above and left of it is loser box.

Everything to right and below of **G7** (G8 and H7) is a loser box so it is a winner box.

**G7** is a winner box so everything above and left of it is loser box.

And so on…

Player one that starts the game has only choice to go to a loser box so **player two always wins**.

All player two has to do is to move to a w box every time it's his turn.

Comment: thanks for including the chart. it made it helpful with the description

Answer (score 1):

Player two always wins for a chessboard of any size.  Proof by induction on the size of the board.

The n=1 case can be ignored, so start with n=2; it is clear that Player 2 wins on a 2x2 board.

Assume that Player 2 always wins on a board of size n or less.  On a board of size n+1, Player 1 moves to a position in the left column or the top row.  Player 2 then moves to a position on the diagonal (that's all the strategy you need), which is then a starting position on a board of size n or less.

QED

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth to note, that the game described is in fact a [Nim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) game with two piles seven coins each. The winner of Nim game can be determined by xoring the numbers of coins in each pile. They call it Nim-sum and it gives a value of Sprague-Grundy function. The position is winning whenever Nim-sum is positive. So considering your game: 7^7 = 0, which is a losing position. Every diagonal position is losing since for whatever `x` is, `x^x` is always 0.
The good thing is that using this technique you can play (and win) this game in 3-dimensional and arbitrarily large space, as well as in 4-, 5-dimensional and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A **winning position** has the following properties:

- All terminal positions are winning. In this case the position (8, 8) is a winning position
- All positions that can reach the goal position in a step are winning postions. *I.e.* all positions in the last row or column are winning positions
- If we can move to a losing position then we are in a winning position since the next player cannot win the game
- If we are only able to move to a winning position then we are in a losing position

With that in mind we can create an algorithm that can tell us if the current position is a winning position or a losing one. Using a table (`dpTable`) to store previously calculated results will avoid doing repeated computations.

```java
boolean isWinning(int x, int y) {
    if (dpTable[x][y] != null)
        return dpTable[x][y];

    // From the last row or the last column we can always win the game
    if (x == n || y == n)
        return true;

    for (int i = 1; x + i <= n; i++) {
        // Moving right
        if (x + i <= n && !isWinning(x+i, y) {
            dpTable[x][y] = true;
            return true;
        }

        // Moving down
        if (y + i <= n && !isWinning(x, y+i) {
            dpTable[x][y] = true;
            return true;
        }
    }

    dpTable[x][y] = false;
    return false;
}
```

The `isWinning(x, y)` function returns `true` when starting from position (x, y) you can win the game by playing optimally and `false` when there is no way for you to start at (x, y) and win.